# Reading from a constantly updating vector

Tags: c++, vector, thread-safety

Heres my scenario.

I've got a vector which contains Vec2s that I'm reading from Memory, I do this in a separate thread.

On the main thread is my render loop which loops through my vector and draws them to the screen.

However, my problem being is that from the thread that retrieves the values it's updating that vector frequently so when I go to loop through the vector on my render loop it's causing read access violations as the item its currently on has been removed.

What's going to be the best approach to work around this?

Comment: The "best approach" is to spend some time reading an advanced C++ book and learn how to correctly access shared data from multiple threads, what the rules are, and basic idioms, then take what you've learned and find the errors in your code, and fix them. This is something that only you, and nobody else on stackoverflow.com, can do because only you have the access to the complete code you're working with, knows what it does, and is able to figure out what the problems are and fix them.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of `mutex`es? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock Create a mutex that both the reader and the writer thread have access to. Then, when you want to lock the vector, the reader or writer creates a `std::unique_lock` from the mutex. When the `unique_lock` goes out of scope, it is destroyed, and the mutex is unlocked. Each thread will wait for for the lock to be released before doing work on the vector.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are new to the concept of concurrency. As people have mentioned in the comments before moving forward you need to understand about how to use a shared resource between threads. But still I will explain you how you can correct your current implementation but still you should go through a proper documentation or tutorial on how to use threading. Example:

```
//main program or thread
{
    //initialize vector
    //start secondary thread
    //ask for a lock from os
    //access or write on the vector
    //ask for unlock from os
}

//secondary thread running infinitely and will exit when a desired condition meets
{
    //ask for a lock from os
    //access or write on the vector
    //ask for unlock from os
}
```

Prior to c++11, Linux based OS and  Windows OS had different implementations of mutex. On many legacy systems those are still in use. Like in Linux OS pthread_mutex is available and similarly for Windows it is called CriticalSection. From c++ 11 onwards, these concepts become part of standard and so they can be used without considering platform dependency except compiler should have support for c++11. For more detail understanding on how to safely and correctly use locking mechanism I suggest you to look online for examples.

Thanks. Happy Programming.